# How to build boost-1.57 with custom STLport on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I would like to build boost-1.57 with head of STLport 5.2 branch. Earlier boost versions had user-config.jam file where I could point the STLport version and location, but I cannot find such possibility in boost-1.57. It seems that boost-1.57 searches stlport in some default system locations, but I want to build STLport and boost in the scope of my account. Any ideas how to do it without cracking boost-1.57 build system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the user-config.jam file in your home directory.

You can see how boost checks for configuration files [here](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html).

After that you should follow the guidelines [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641030/unable-to-build-boost-with-stlport-library) to build with STLport, with some minor modifications for Linux.

Comment: To be honest I tried user-config.jam in boost directory (according to [this manual](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html)), not my home directory, and it seemed it didn't work. OK, I will try your way. Thanks.

Comment: You are right, it works in home directory. I really appreciate boost but the documentation in such cases just pisses me off.